# Django Error: Could not import settings 'interfaces.settings'

Tags: python, django

So, I'm fairly new to programming. I have relatively little background in django and don't understand much of its implementation. However I have read through django tutorials and have a basic understanding of the underlying structure.

So currently I am not actually modifying the django project being used by the server (lets call it `/mai`n), I think my coworker copied over the project to a new directory called `/test`. When I try to do anything with `manage.py` located in the `/test` directory by running

```
python2.4 manage.py runserver
```

I get an error saying

```
Django Error: Could not import settings 'interfaces.settings' 
  (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings.
```

I've looked through the settings file and have tried changing `main` to `test`, but it hasn't changed anything.

Any guidance as to where I should look for a solution would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Also?

It sounds like there is something hard-coded somewhere which expects the project to be in a directory called "interfaces", rather than "test". Try running `manage.py shell --settings=settings`, and see if that helps.

Actually, "also", you should not be editing code on the server, even if it's in a different directory to the production deployment. Install Django and the code on your local machine, and edit there.

Comment: So I did that, now its saying could not import test.settings. 
So I tried 
`python2.4 manage.py runserver --settings=settings`
 and it ran fine. However when it is run without that argument it won't run.

Comment: I have the same problem, and specifying --settings worked for me too! As it's obviously not in the settings file itself, any thoughts on where to look for the hardcoded value?

Answer (score 2):

The `manage.py shell --settings=settings` worked for me.  I figured out from running `django-admin.py runserver` that settings could not be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE was undefined.

**Fix:**  `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings`

I ran the command from the root of the project (same directory that had manage.py -- not sure if it matters).  Then, running `manage.py shell` worked *without* the `--settings=settings` bit.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to undestand which versions of python you have installed.

Type python2 and press tab button in console.

It looks, that you are trying to run version of python, which has not django installed in libs.

Also try to run python2.4 in interactive mode from test folder and import settings.